# Change default folder for Win-R

Tags: windows-7, windows, run-dialog

Is there a way to tell the Windows Run Dialog (<kbd>Win-R</kbd>) to start programs in a folder other than `C:\Users\<username>\`?

Comment: Are you asking about the working folder programs run from Win+R use, or are you asking about running CMD and having the command prompt starting in your user folder?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 both. I think it's the same thing

Answer (score -1):

Just add to your (user-defined, or global, as you want) $PATH variable the directory you want windows to start programs from.